# How to convert an 8086 emu assembly program to linux assembly comaptible

Tags: linux, assembly, compiler-errors, att, emu8086

I am writing a code  to convert hex (A-F) to decimal in assembly. I managed to write it on 8086 emu but I need it for linux. I need help.

The code works absolutely fine on 8086 emulator n windows. But I am unable to convert it into Linux syntax. I am not familiar with the Linux Syntax for assembly.

This is my 8686 code.

```
org 100h
.model small
.stack 100h
.data
msg1 db 'Enter a hex digit:$'
msg2 db 'In decimal it is:$'
.code
main proc
mov ax,@data
mov ds,ax
lea dx,msg1
mov ah,9
int 21h

mov ah,1
int 21h
mov bl,al
sub bl,17d ; convert to corrosponding hex value
mov ah,2
mov dl,0dh
int 21h
mov dl,0ah
int 21h
lea dx,msg2
mov ah,9
int 21h
mov dl,49d ;print 1 at first
mov ah,2
int 21h
mov dl,bl
mov ah,2 ; print next value of hex after 1
int 21h
main endp
end main
ret
```

Comment: Linux is an operating system, what you probably mean is x86 assembly - that's the processor architecture.

Comment: There's no "Linux syntax", but the way you interact with the OS from your code is different. See e.g. https://jameshfisher.com/2018/03/10/linux-assembly-hello-world/

Answer (score 1):

To do such a conversion, you have to consider two things:

1. Your code is segmented 16-bit assembly code. Linux does not use segmented 16-bit code, but either flat 32-bit or 64-bit code.

   "Flat" means that the selectors (`cs`, `ds`, `es`, `ss` which are not "segment" registers but "selectors" in 32-bit mode) have a pre-defined value which should not be changed.

   In 32-bit mode the CPU instructions (and therefore the assembler instructions) are a bit different from 16-bit mode.
2. Interrupts are environment dependent. `int 21h` for example is an MS-DOS interrupt, which means that `int 21h` is only available if the operating system used is compatible to MS-DOS or you use some software (such as "8086 emu") that emulates MS-DOS.

   x86 Linux uses `int 80h` in 32-bit programs to call operating system functions. Unfortunately, many quite "handy" functions of `int 21h` are not present in Linux. One example would be keyboard input:

   If you don't want the default behavior (complete lines are read with echo; the program can read the first character of a line when a complete line has been typed), you'll have to send a so-called `ioctl()`-code to the system...

   And of course the syntax of Linux system calls is different to MS-DOS ones: Function `EAX=9` of `int 80h` (link a file on the disk) is a completely different function than `AH=9` of `int 21h` (print a string on the screen).

You have tagged your question with the tag `att`. There are however also assemblers for Linux that can assemble `intel`-style assembly code.

Comment: Hello Martin, Thanks for the explaination. Then Can I get some converter which can convert this code to 32 bit architecture as I am not familiar with that architecture at all.

Comment: @user3260225: no, there aren't tools to automatically port from 16-bit DOS code to 32-bit Linux code.  If you want to run DOS programs under Linux, you'd normally use an emulator like DOSBOX.  If you want a Linux program, you'd write a Linux program.  Other than system calls, though, 16-bit code will usually assemble just fine in 32-bit mode, using 16-bit registers.  It's usually less efficient, but you usually only *need* to port the system calls, and there aren't 1:1 equivalents for most of them, as Martin said.